# Wordpress upgrade from 2.7 to 3.3 Permalink problem

Tags: permalinks, themes, theme-twenty-eleven, upgrade

I have upgraded my wordpress from 2.7 to 3.3.  Now if I try to change my Permalink /%category%/%postname%/  my home page is loading.  However,  all my pages are getting 404 page.

I dont know how to fix the problem...  I got no log..  Then I changed the theme to default theme twenty eleven then also I faced the same issue.

Then I installed a new WP 3.3 then installed put my theme alone..  now no menu is displayed..  I dont know what is the problem.. any help is greatly appreciated..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: One, a live link would be really helpful here. Two, it is unclear if this is *one* issue or *two* separate issues: permalinks/rewrites, and navigation menu. For the latter, we need to see your custom-Theme navigation menu code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because in wp_options table I had ./ for home (row id 37)variable. I replaced with ""(blank) now the issue fixed..

Answer (score 1):

Never try to upgrade that many versions in a single step! You will need to carry out a series of smaller, manual, upgrades:
 2.7 -> 2.8 -> 2.9 -> 3.0 -> 3.2 -> 3.3.1 ->3.3

I would deactivate all plugins and switch to default theme
 when you get to current version, switch themes to what you are using and see if it breaks - if so, it will need to be updated
- start activating plugins one by one to make sure they work - I'm sure all of them will prompt for an upgrade - you should do that 1st

Comment: Actually I have upgraded everything...  currently all plugins wordpress and theme everything is upgraded...

Comment: I dont know what and where went wrong..  I installed a new version of wordpress and put the theme alone then also there was a problem menus everything got scattered..

Comment: During upgrade do they upgraded any menu code..

Comment: during auto upgrade, all the core files including wo-content folder get updated

Comment: Hay thanks for all your help finally I found out one bug.  The problem is because in wp_options table I had ./ for home (row id 37)variable.  Because of that only all the issues.  I dont know how it got corrupted.